# How to figure out if my JSONArray includes a certain JSONArray or not?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse the following type of JSONArray:

> [{"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","mac":["86:2b:a2:f1:2b:9c"],"ipv4":["10.0.0.1"],"ipv6":[],"vlan":["0x0"],"attachmentPoint":[{"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02","port":1,"errorStatus":null}],"lastSeen":1456312407529},{"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","mac":["1e:94:63:67:1e:d1"],"ipv4":["10.0.0.3"],"ipv6":[],"vlan":["0x0"],"attachmentPoint":[{"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03","port":1,"errorStatus":null}],"lastSeen":1456312407625},{"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","mac":["06:d7:e0:c5:60:86"],"ipv4":["10.0.0.2"],"ipv6":[],"vlan":["0x0"],"attachmentPoint":[{"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02","port":2,"errorStatus":null}],"lastSeen":1456312407591},{"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","mac":["6e:c3:e4:5e:1f:65"],"ipv4":["10.0.0.4"],"ipv6":[],"vlan":["0x0"],"attachmentPoint":[{"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03","port":2,"errorStatus":null}],"lastSeen":1456312407626}]

The problem is, sometimes there is the "attachmentPoint" JSONArray and sometimes there is not. If it is not there I get the nasty exception text in my output. How can I check if it will be there before I try to run my code?

I currently have the following:

```
if (fldevices.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("attachmentPoint").getJSONObject(0).has("switchDPID")
```

But obviously that won't work since it already tries to access attachmentPoint, and if it isn't there I get the error. Is there something similar to .has() for Arrays?

Comment: Simply get `attachmentPoint` first and check for its null-ability before performing any further operation on it like . `JSONArray attachmentPoint = fldevices.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("attachmentPoint"); if(attachmentPoint != null){...}`

Comment: "Is there something similar to .has() for Arrays" - Did you try `fldevices.getJSONObject(i).has("attachmentPoint")`?

Comment: Thanks @Braj that worked perfectly!

Comment: @Thomas actually yes, .has("attachmentPoint") works but I said it wrong before, the attachmentPoint array is there, it's just empty. And I didn't manage to check whether it contained anything using .has. However, checking if it's null does the same.

Comment: Hmm, if the array is there it shouldn't be null (however, if it's implemented using maps it might be null while the key still exists). I'd probably also check the array size if it's not null because it might exist but just be empty.

Answer (score 0):

use `has` method to check the existence of `attachmentPoint`.

E.g. :

```
if(fldevices.getJSONObject(i).has("attachmentPoint")){
  //process attachmentPoint
}
```

Comment: My bad, it actually always exists but I needed to check if it's empty. I didn't manage to do that with .has but checking if it's null or not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
public static Object opt(Object json, String path) {
    for (String key : path.split("\\.")) {
        if (json == null)
            return null;
        if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            if (!key.matches("\\d+"))
                return null;
            json = ((JSONArray)json).opt(Integer.parseInt(key));
        } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            json = ((JSONObject)json).opt(key);
        } else
            return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

This method retrieve JSONObject or JSONArray by path.
If the path is invalid, it returns null.
Never throws exception.

For example

```
System.out.println(opt(fldevices, "0.attachmentPoint.0.switchDPID"));
System.out.println(opt(fldevices, "0.INVALID_KEY.0.switchDPID"));
System.out.println(opt(fldevices, "0.attachmentPoint.999.switchDPID"));
```

output

```
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02
null
null
```

So you can write like this.

```
if (opt(fldevices, i + ".attachmentPoint.0.switchDPID") != null)
```